# Finding duplicate Records php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have check the other post about this but nothing seems to work for me.  I have a MySQL database called cmd table called insta, with two col named vid ( int(11) and url (TEXT).  What I want to do is find any duplicate url and display both the vid and the url.  I have tried.

```
SELECT vid, url FROM insta
GROUP BY vid, url
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Even though them seems to work for other people it's not working for me. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Maybe for the same duplicate url vid is different, do you have any sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    a.vid as vid1,
    b.vid as vid2,
    a.url
from
    insta a
inner join
    insta b
on
    a.url = b.url
where
    a.vid <> b.vid
```

Comment: I got this error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'a' (T_STRING) for the 2nd line of code. @Aitch

Comment: your error message (...T_STRING...) is a PHP error right? I wrote a SQL query.

Comment: Yes, I copyed your code in to a php file and put in like this
<?php


select
    a.vid as vid1,
    b.vid as vid2,
    a.url
from
    insta a
inner join
    insta b
on
    a.url = b.url
where
    a.vid <> b.vid


?>
@Aitch

Comment: oh man sorry, I will not tell you how to connect to the database and make a query. copy my query into phpmyadmin and check it out.

Comment: I was able to use your code from phpmyadmin.  Do you know how to get this to work from a php file.  i would like it echo out the duplicats @aitch

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-connect.php http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php you can do it.